# keep getting these error messages..compile error

Tags: verilog

This is my code. But when I compile this, I got error messages.

What's wrong with my code?

```
// seg7dec.v
module seg7dec (
input [3:0] val,
output reg [6:0] seg // from MSB  A, B, C, D, E, F, G 
);
always @(*)
begin
case (val[3:0])
4'h0: seg[6:0] = 7'b111_1110;
4'h1: seg[6:0] = 7'b011_0000;
4'h2: seg[6;0] = 7'b110_1101;                                                                 
4'h3: seg[6;0] = 7'b111_1001;
4'h4: seg[6;0] = 7'b011_0011;         
4'h5: seg[6;0] = 7'b101_1011; 
4'h6: seg[6;0] = 7'b101_1111; 
4'h7: seg[6;0] = 7'b111_0000;
4'h8: seg[6;0] = 7'b111_1111;
4'h9: seg[6;0] = 7'b111_1011;
4'ha: seg[6;0] = 7'b111_1101;
4'hb: seg[6;0] = 7'b001_1111;
4'hc: seg[6;0] = 7'b100_1110;
4'hd: seg[6;0] = 7'b100_1111;
4'hg: seg[6;0] = 7'b111_1011;
default: seg[6:0] = 7'b100_0111 ; // 4'hF
endcase
end
endmodule
```

These are the error messages:

```
;'.
** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(14): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(15): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(16): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(17): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(18): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(19): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(20): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(21): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(22): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'.

** Error: (vlog-13057) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(23): Expecting numeric digits.

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Intel/seg7dec.v(23): near "g": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ':'.
```

Answer (score 2):

From the line

`4'h2: seg[6;0] = 7'b110_1101;`

You have added **; instead of :** between 6 and 0.

Answer (score 2):

1. When using partial select, the format should be `[MSB:LSB]`.
   So you need to change `seg[6;0]` to `seg[6:0]`.
   Or, since `seg` is declared as 7-bit wide, it's not necessary to add `[6:0]` to `seg`.
2. The last `4'hg` should be `4'he`.